# does an object need to be initialized before for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, initialization

am wondering if I an create an object within a for loop - i.e. don't have to initialize it. I have tried this how one might do it in matlab. Please see the following R code:

```
> for (i in 1:nrow(snp.ids)) {
+ snp.fasta[i]<-entrez_fetch(db="protein", id=snp.ids[i,], rettype="xml",retmode="text")
+ snp.seq[i]<-xpathSApply(xmlParse(snp.fasta[i]), "//Seq-data_iupacaa",xmlValue)
+ }
Error in snp.fasta[i] <- entrez_fetch(db = "protein", id = snp.ids[i,  : 
  object 'snp.fasta' not found
```

where it obviously does not find snp.fasta - but you can see from the code I am trying to create snp.fasta. can anyone shed any light on why it would not create it within. the for loop, and what would be the proper way to initialize snp.fasta if I cannot create it within the for loop.

Thanks

Comment: There are ways to do this but I can't think of any benefit to doing so. Since you already know the size of `snp.fasta`, you might as well initialize it with the appropriate length, i.e. `snp.fasta <- vector(); length(snp.fasta) <- nrow(snp.ids)`, before your loop to avoid the memory allocation overhead related to growing a vector incrementally.

Comment: thank you - this makes sense to me now. in matlab I have always created it within the for loop, but maybe I shouldn't have been doing that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally , yes. That would be an acceptable way to loop over a vector of ids. Just assign to a non-indexed object.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(snp.ids)) {
 snp.fasta <- entrez_fetch(db="protein", id=snp.ids[i,], rettype="xml",retmode="text")
 snp.seq <- xpathSApply(xmlParse(snp.fasta), "//Seq-data_iupacaa",xmlValue)
 }
```

(You would then still need to assign any useful result to an index-able object or build a sequence of such within the loop or print some result. As it stands this example will over-write all the values of snp.seq and leave only the last one. )

It's a bit confusing to see `id=snp.ids[i,]`. That would imply that snp.ids has a dimension of 2. I would have expected a column name or number to be used: `id=snp.ids[i,"id"]`. You should provide `dput(head(snp.ids))` so we can do some realistic testing rather than this half-assed guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

In R, subsetting is also a function, so assigning value to an item in a vector:

```
a[1] = 123
```

is identical to

```
"["(a, 1) = 123
```

Here `[` is a normal function. If `a` is not defined, there is an error.

Answer (score 0):

Before the loop:

```
snp.fasta <- NULL
```